# Rules Clarification in Tag Badges Tab

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges

I'd like to suggest that the page https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags (and similar) make a clear point that tag badges can be *lost* if your reputation in the specific tag decreases below the given threshold.

As it currently stands, the description for (bronze) badges says "Earned 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers [...]", which may be interpreted as, once you *earned* those points, you got the badge and no one can take it from you.

Comment: Maybe a link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions will do it?